# WebDriver implicit wait is not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

1. WebDriver implicit wait is waiting for only 10 seconds even if I give 30 or 60 seconds, control moving to the next step before loading the page. `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
   Here I have defined implicit timeout like above, Please correct me if i need to add any code other code to this?
2. Do we have any method in webdriver for waitforPageToLoad? I tried with `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` but it isn't working as expected.

Please assist me on this.

Comment: In selenium WebDriver you do not need to put implicit wait for page load WebDriver automaticly manage this task. till your web page is not loaded fully it would not execute next command.

Comment: Naveen, it did not wait until the page/element wait, i did R&D on this and then posted this question.

Comment: You are abusing implicit waits. Set it once, and once only, at the very start of the driver construction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for particular element to load its better to use Explicit waits

Comment: Yes I can use explicit wait, but I just wanted to know, does implicitwait work or not? Why it implicitwait is taking only 10 Seconds?

Answer (score 0):

When you say implicit wait takes only 10 seconds, what do you mean? Do you mean WebDriver is taking only 10 seconds to find element when you sent implicitly wait to 30s? Are you sure something else is not breaking, giving you a false sense that implicitly wait is not working?

I have answered a similar question in the past regarding implicit and explicit wait with examples. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008302/selenium-common-exceptions-staleelementreferenceexception-during-page-refresh/16020069#16020069). It also talks about generic waits strategy etc.

Comment: nilesh, here webdriver control is moving to the next step before loading the page completely, it waits for only 10 seconds

Comment: Ok. Is this something you can reproduce on a public website? If so, please update your question and file a bug on google selenium project. As for your issue, I think you need to use a combination of explicit wait and generic wait I mentioned in above link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to use implicit wait while for a specific issue and found that it doesn't do the job it is ought to do. FluentWait works out well.

I ended up using Thread.sleep() to forcefully halt the running process and it did furnish my job.

BTW: I tested it on Firefox 27 and 31 versions. Don't know of other browsers!